# BIM360 model vesrion diff (comparison) returns data, even if same model uploaded as different versions

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to fetch difference between two versions of a model uploaded over BIM360 platform. For that I'm using the provided API by BIM360 for comparison

```
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/index-v2-diff-properties-get/
```

The issue is when we are calling the API with same model uploaded as version one and version two, it still giving the data in return as OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED. But nothing has removed or changed as we uploaded same model both the time.(We observed change in lmvId and databaseId which should not appear for same model)

We tried multiple times with multiple model files but facing the same issues. What we were expecting that it should show OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED or OBJECT CHANGED only when there is an actual change in the version of the model we are comparing to. If no change in both version of model it should not return anything. If there is removal, addition or modification of object then only it should return the result data as OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED or OBJECT CHANGED.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is true there is specific scenario that model properties API reports unexpected change. What I experienced was:  they are not geometry objects, but virtual items such as level, view ,section box  etc.  These virtual objects are in the SVF(1) property DB and extracted into the property index. Diffing then picks up these objects, because they have different IDs.

Comment: Another scenario is the model (v1) was saved in a previous old release, but re-saved in higher released of Revit. From certain release, the unit format of Revit is changed, so that  would also cause the diff

Comment: if you could provide a sample model, I will further investigate. you can email to aps.help@autodesk.com with this Stackoverflow link as reference. cc to xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com, Thank you.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I have mailed the sample model and its result to aps.help@autodesk.com with you xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com in cc. 
Request no: 16713. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Does the model version diff result appear the same?

Comment: I received your test sample and found those Added/Removed elements are some hidden elements that are not geometries. Their views or bounding-box is null. So if you only want to check the difference of geometries, you could specify the filter when query diff data or filter after getting the diff data. I will wait for your further reply in that private email. And finally summarize in Stackverflow