# BIM 360 diff (comparison) malfunction

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Detailed Question:

I'm trying to fetch difference between two versions of a model uploaded over BIM360 platform. For that I'm using the provided API by BIM360 for comparison

The issue is when we are calling the API with same model uploaded as version one and version two, it still giving the data in return as OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED. But nothing has removed or changed as we uploaded same model both the time.(We observed change in lmvId and databaseId which should not appear for same model)

We tried multiple times with multiple model files but facing the same issues. What we were expecting that it should show OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED or OBJECT CHANGED only when there is an actual change in the version of the model we are comparing to. If no change in both version of model it should not return anything. If there is removal, addition or modification of object then only it should return the result data as OBJECT REMOVED, OBJECT ADDED or OBJECT CHANGED.

Referance

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140387/bim360-model-vesrion-diff-comparison-returns-data-even-if-same-model-uploaded
```

Comment: same question with the other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140387/bim360-model-vesrion-diff-comparison-returns-data-even-if-same-model-uploaded. will discuss on the other thread

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Yes please